# PHP Ldap AD - Reconhecer dados do usuário automaticamente sem login

Tags: php, ad, ldap

Pretendo fazer uma aplicação no PHP que não necessite o já batido usuário e senha para login. Como temos Active Directory aqui na empresa, a princípio pensei em fazer com que o usuário ao entrar no link da aplicação, já aparecesse os dados dele do AD.

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo que você precisa é o modulo do Apache [`mod_auth_sspi`](http://mod-auth-sspi.sourceforge.net/) .

Exemplo de configuração:

```
AuthType SSPI
SSPIAuth On
SSPIAuthoritative On
SSPIDomain mydomain

# Set this if you want to allow access with clients that do not support NTLM, or via proxy from outside. Don't forget to require SSL in this case!
SSPIOfferBasic On

# Set this if you have only one domain and don't want the MYDOMAIN\ prefix on each user name
SSPIOmitDomain On

# AD user names are case-insensitive, so use this for normalization if your application's user names are case-sensitive
SSPIUsernameCase Lower
AuthName "Some text to prompt for domain credentials"
Require valid-user
```

E não esqueça que você pode [utilizar o Firefox para o SSO transparente no dominio Windows] (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris):

Vá em `about:config`, pesquise por `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`, e insira o hostname ou FQDN da sua aplicação interna (tipo myserver ou myserver.corp.domain.com).

Você pode ter mais de uma entrada, é um campo separado por vírgulas.
Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003751/how-can-i-implement-single-sign-on-sso-using-microsoft-ad-for-an-internal-php

Comment: Eu procurei no httpd.conf do Apache e não achei o mod_auth_sspi. Devo incluir em alguma linha "LoadModule..."? 
E esse exemplo de configuração que você mandou vai onde?
To meio perdido nisso...

Comment: @GustavoMacielSetta da uma olhada nessa documentação https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/HelpOnInstalling/ApacheOnWin32withDomainAuthentication

Comment: Mais uma para ajudar https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/91377-implementing-single-sign-on-on-windows-with-apache @GustavoMacielSetta

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mas aqui não funcionou nenhum tutorial. Toda vez que mexo no arquivo httpd.conf o Apache não sobe novamente. Estou usando o Xampp para fazer o teste, exatamente como diz nesse último link que você mandou. Agradeço a ajuda, mas vou desistir, vi que dá infinitamente mais trabalho do que fazer a tela de login! Obrigado novamente!